# LINQ запрос с условием и преобразование данных используя методы расширений?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

У меня есть запрос:

```
var postsData = dbContext.posts.ToList();
```

В этой коллекции я хочу преобразовать объекты у которого есть текстовое поле TextPost. Например, в каждой строке оставить только 4 символа, если строка > 4.

```
            for (int i = 0; i > postsData.Count; i++)
        {
            if (postsData[i].TextPost.Length > 4)
            {
                postsData[i].TextPost = postsData[i].TextPost.Remove(4, postsData[i].TextPost.Length - 4) + "....";
            }
        }

        return postsData;
```

Мне не нравится данное действие указаное выше, поэтому я бы хотел знать, как построить LINQ запрос, который сразу находит строчки у которых больше, чем 4 символа, и обрезает их занося в коллекцию.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение сделал :3

```
 IEnumerable<Post> postsData = dbContext.posts
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(text =>
            {
                if(text.TextPost.Length > 200)
                    text.TextPost = text.TextPost.Remove(200, text.TextPost.Length - 200) + "...";
                else
                    text.TextPost += "...";

                return text;
            } ) .ToList();
```